# MsoNormal in mail footer signature. How to remove?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I made mail signature in HTML.
All code was included to Outlook 2013.

Now Outlook sends e-mail with added styles and tags and mail footer looks very bad.

How can I force that?

Outlok add class: MsoNormal
and lot of other thing:

```
<p>, <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Novasol's answer (which I agree with) I also wanted to add my small improvement.

Outlook has automatically converted the "px" (pixels) to "pt" (points). So, better add "pt" in the CSS styling as follows to better control your desired result:

```css
td p {margin: .25pt !important}
```

For reference: the 1px became .75pt.

The recommended and lowest (accepted) value should be .25pt (called "hairline"). There is a massive visual difference between .75pt and .25pt.

Hope this helps and improves your signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with a margin on paragraphs, you can open html file with your signature at c:\Users\ **YOUR_USER_PROFILE** \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\ **your_signature.htm** and put something like the code bellow, just before the end tag of the head.

```
...
<style>
td p { margin: 1px !important;}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: I have put margin: 1px, because Gmail does not use 0px at all.